# Asp.Net Core, [FromQuery] complex class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the followings classes:

```
public class TextFilter
{
    public string Value { get; set; } = "";
    public EnumTextFilterSearchMethod SearchMethod { get; set; } = EnumTextFilterSearchMethod.EQ;
}

public class ContractsFilter
{
    public TextFilter ContractNumber { get; set; } = new TextFilter();

    public TextFilter OrderNumber { get; set; } = new TextFilter();
}
```

and controller:

```
[HttpGet("")]
public IActionResult Contracts([FromQuery] ContractsFilter filter = null)
```

the query string appears as:

```
http://localhost:63553/contracts?ContractNumber=my.namespace.TextFilter&OrderNumber=my.namespace.TextFilter
```

But I would need that the query string is formed as following:

```
http://localhost:63553/contracts?ContractNumber.Value=any_contract_number&ContractNumber.SearchMethod=EQ&OrderNumber.Value=any_order_number&OrderNumber.SearchMethod=EQ
```

If I enter so the query string by hand, the controller can it parse properly.

How can I make the class ContractsFilter appears in the query string with all properties of class TextFilter?

Comment: How did you generate the query string?

Comment: I do not generate the query string. The URL with "contracts?ContractNumber=my.namespace.TextFilter&..." appears in the browser, generated by asp.net core after call RedirectToAction(nameof(Contracts), new ContractsFilter { ContractNumber = new TextFilter { Value = "185475", SearchMethod = TextFilter.EnumTextFilterSearchMethod.EQ } }); After that, when I do refresh in the browser, the object ContractNumber is empty. That`s why I need the query string to be generated as "contracts?ContractNumber.Value=185475&ContractNumber.SearchMethod=EQ".

Answer (score 0):

Try the `[FromUri]` attribute before your in-parameter in the same way you’ve tried with the `[FromBody]` attribute.